# Why This Flutter code not working after removing onTap and OtherCallBacks

Tags: flutter

I 'am new to Flutter and currently practicing. I am Learning from Official Docs and Try This by own (removing ontap). But it doesn't work why please tell.
I' am only trying to understand the structure so i tried this after reading official docs. But it shows error. I Go back to docs I am not able to found where is my mistake please help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  Product({this.name});
  final String name;
}

class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  Item({this.product});
  final Product product;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(product.name[0]),
      ),
      title: Text(product.name),
    );
  }
}

class MyShoppingList extends StatefulWidget {
  MyShoppingList({this.products});
  final List<Product> products;

  @override
  _MyShoppingListState createState() => _MyShoppingListState();
}

class _MyShoppingListState extends State<MyShoppingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shopping List"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
              Item(product: product);
            }).toList(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

main() {
  return runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyShoppingList(
      products: <Product>[
        Product(name: "Hello"),
        Product(name: "World"),
        Product(name: "")
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: May I know what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your code:

**First:** You are using a listView inside a column and both have unbounded heights.

***The Solution:***  for example you can wrap the listview with a `Expanded` like the following:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
            return Item(product: product);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

**Second problem:** You need a return keyword inside the map method.

```
 ListView(
           children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
             // You need to return the Item widget here.
             return Item(product: product);
            }).toList(),
        ),
```

**Third problem:** You are trying to show the first character of the `product.name` inside the `listTile` widget which maybe null sometimes, So you have to check if `product.name` is `null` first.

***Solution***

```
ListTile(
  leading: CircleAvatar(
    child: Text(
        product.name == null || product.name == "" ? " " : product.name[0]),
  ),
  title: Text(product.name),
)
```

**The final code will be:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  Product({this.name});
  final String name;
}

class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  Item({this.product});
  final Product product;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(
            product.name == null || product.name == "" ? " " : product.name[0]),
      ),
      title: Text(product.name),
    );
  }
}

class MyShoppingList extends StatefulWidget {
  MyShoppingList({this.products});
  final List<Product> products;

  @override
  _MyShoppingListState createState() => _MyShoppingListState();
}

class _MyShoppingListState extends State<MyShoppingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shopping List"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
                return Item(product: product);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

main() {
  return runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyShoppingList(
      products: <Product>[
        Product(name: "Hello"),
        Product(name: "World"),
        Product(name: "")
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 things you should do, first >the map should return the widget, Second >wrap your listview in Expanded.

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
                return Item(product: product);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          )
```